# My php contact form is redirecting on an error 500

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I launched my websites a few hours ago, and I can't get my contact form to work !
I followed many tutorials, but none worked for me, there must be an error somewhere...

Here is my HTML form, visibile on my main page, index.html :

```
<form action="mail.php" class="contact-form" method="POST">
<fieldset>

    <input name="obj" type="text"><br>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>

    <input name="from-name" type="text"><br> 
    <input name="from-mail" type="text"><br> 

    <input type="submit" value="Send">

</fieldset></form>
```

And here is the content of my mail.php file, inside the same folder that index.html on my server. mail.php includes ONLY the following code, nothing else.

```
<?php $name = $_POST['from-name'];
$email = $_POST['from-mail'];
$obj = $_POST['obj'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent="from: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "XXX.XXX@gmail.com";
$subject = "$obj";
$mailheader = "from: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href="index.html"> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

So here it here, whenever I click on my submit button, Chrome instantly redirects me on a server error 500, no message sent.
Where have I made a mistake ?

Comment: Change `<a href="index.html">` to `<a href='index.html'>` !!

Comment: Replace `echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href="index.html"> Return Home</a>";` with `echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html'> Return Home</a>";`, You can't use (") inside another (").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href="index.html"> Return Home</a>";
```

to this

```
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html'> Return Home</a>";
```

**Improved code**

```
if (!mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {
    die("Error!");
}
else
{
    echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html'>Return Home</a>";
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @keyloags happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

"500 Internal Server Error" occurs when your php code has fatal errors but error displaying is turned off. You may try this to see the error.

In your php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And

In .htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```